# Meta tags with slim-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, metadata, meta-tags, slim-lang

I am currently working on a site sweep and am attempting to refine meta presentation for an app already in production. Specifically, the tags seem to live in the _head.html.slim file.

Example of way meta tag is currently represented in app:

```
    - if content_for?(:description)
meta name="description" content=content_for(:description)
```

What I would like to replace it with:

```
    <meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION OF SITE HERE"/>
```

Am I on the correct track? I am hesitant to completely wipe the "if content_for?(:description) bit.

I have not worked with slim-rails before, and am thrown off. I've gone through some of the documentation on slim gem, but it defines implementation of meta tags in a completely different manner than what I am currently seeing in the _head.html.slim file.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content_for` is [actually part of Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html) and has very little to do with Slim. [`yield` and `content_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) let you assign "blocks" of content in your layouts that can be filled dynamically by views.

This is a plain ERB example of dynamically assigning a page title:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<title>MyApp | <%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Foo" %>
```

Then in your views you can provide content with content for:

```
# app/views/products.html.erb
<%- contents_for(:title, "Products" ) -%>
```

The end result is that the page title will read `MyApp | Products` when you visit `/products`.

For your example you could simply provide the content for the description in your views.

```
# app/views/user/show.slim
- content_for(:description, "#{ @user.name } on MyApp")
# or we use provide to tell the layout to stop looking for more contents.
- provide(:description, "#{ @user.name } on MyApp")
```

And set it up to display a default in case there is no content provided.

```
= meta name="description" content= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "The awesomest app on the interwebs."
```

To clean this up you might want to employ a helper method.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # ...
  def og_description(default)
    # note that we use content_for and not yield since we want
    # the value - not to yield (print) to the buffer.
    disc = content_for?(:description) ? content_for(:description) : default 
    tag(:meta, {
      property: "og:description",
      content: disc
    })
  end
end
```

This will let you do:

```
= og_description("The awesomest app on the interwebs.")
```

Comment: I would encourage you to read the rails guide and the api documentation because it can be difficult at times to understand how the flow of how rails renders and there are several gotchas when it comes to caching.

Comment: First and foremost: THANK YOU for such a great explanation. I am going through some rails guides/api docs as I type!

Your explanation completely cleared that up for me.Now, based on what I learned.. I could simply replace the line with: 
- if content_for?(:description)
meta property="og:description" content=content_for(:description)"

and should be fine, correct?

In regards to adding helpers.. in your example, you created a method for og_description. This means, if I did end up going the helper route, I could create additional methods (og_locale, og_title) in the same file..correct?

Comment: `I could simply replace the line with: - if content_for?(:description) meta property="og:description" content=content_for(:description)" and should be fine, correct?`. If what you want is for there to be og:description meta tag only if `content_for?(:description)` is true then yes.

Comment: Methods declared in your ApplicationHelper are available in all your views. So yes you can create `og_locale`, `og_title` etc in the same file.